# Update application to AppStore listed app from TestFlight beta app

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, testflight, beta-testing

Apple allows External testers to beta test builds through TestFlight for 30 days after which the build will expire. My questions are the following:

1) Will the application stop working after 30 days ? or Will TestFlight just make the build inactive after 30 days ?

2) If the main build submitted App Store gets approved and if we send a link to all the external testers. Can they be able to just update the app or do they need to uninstall the beta built app and install fresh ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer for your questions:

1. After 30 days app will automatically inactive. You can't download it again from Testflight.
2. You don't have to remove beta build application. You can download directly from the app store.

Comment: The app data download from App store overwrite, original stored data are preserved or cleared  ?

Answer (score 2):

1. You cant test after 30 days.
2. Once your app will live you can delete earlier builds

Check this Apple video you will get all information

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DjWrSn1kTBw

You can use [www.diawi.com](http://www.diawi.com) to test build for tester. You just need provisioning profile containing UDID and build. This gives you test link.

Answer (score 1):

1. After 30 days the app will stop working. Also we will not be able to download it again.
2. Well you can directly install an app from the app store without removing TestFlight app from your device. It will overwrite.