# Will the released AppStore app replace Testflight app by notifying the user to update their app on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

I currently have App v1.0 approved for beta testing to external testers and have sent out the appropriate email.

I recently also submitted App v1.0 for AppStore and is waiting for review.

My question is, once the app has been approved for download on the AppStore, will users be notified to update the existing beta test App to the one available on the AppStore "when" they open the AppStore app, or will it be a separate App where they have to search for it and download it?

I found a similar question here: [Update application to AppStore listed app from TestFlight beta app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31674358/update-application-to-appstore-listed-app-from-testflight-beta-app)

However, the answer provided did not directly answer the question I have.

I also found this:
[Will testflight prerelease beta app version update existing App Store version, or install another instance of the app on tester's device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32655508/will-testflight-prerelease-beta-app-version-update-existing-app-store-version-o)

However, that's the opposite of what I'm asking.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so. In my experience, the test flight version is not seen as an app store app, so no update will be suggested. In addition, test flight users will typically have an equal or greater version number than the app on the app store, so there would be little point to "updating" to the app store version.

Comment: Thanks, I also confirmed your statement elsewhere.